# Compare 2 files and print matching values to a new file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file which contains 12 Million lines each line is broken into 8 parts all of which are separated by ";".
File1 Example: 
`AAA;BBB;CCC;DDD;EEE;FFF;GGGXX;HHH`

Each line has a unique ID in $7.
I have another file (File2) which has ~20K of these unique IDs listed as:

`GGGXX;
GGGXY;
GGGXZ;`

Each on its own line.

I need the result to create a new file with the complete data row from File1 based on the IDs in File2.

I cannot seem to get it to work when File2 has more than 1 entry using the code below.

```
awk -F ";" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]} ($7 in a){print}' File2.txt File1.txt
```

Is there something wrong with how the IDs are listed in File2 or is there something else that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you aware that `'F` should be `-F`? Is that just a typo?

Comment: This is not a bug, but it's a bit sloppy: `a[$21++]` -- that creates an array key for the value field 21 (the value for that array key is 0 or the empty string), then it increments the field 21 value. The `++` has no effect on the array at all and can be removed. You probably intended `a[$21]++`, but it's not necessary that the array has a value for that key.

Comment: Having said that, you do not actually ask a question in your question. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for your help. I had made some typos. What I am trying to do is have both files compared and as I said in the post, File 1 has all of my data and File 2 $1 has the small group of data that I need to pull out of File 1 $7. When I try this and have File 2 with only 1 data point, it works, But when I have all 20K data points, I am not given any data from File1. I'll edit the main post with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below command to get the required output.

```
awk  -F "," 'NR==FNR {a[$7];next}($1 in a){print $1}' file1 file2 > newfile
```

Comment: It seems that it does not really work the way i needed it to. The issue is that it still does not work when File2 has more than 1 entry. The only way it works is if File 2 has only 1 ID in the txt file. Another issue is that this way only prints out the line of File2 whereas I want to print the matching line in File1 that has the same ID as in File2. 
Thanks